# Can someone explain why I get this error message on localhost:3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost

I keep getting the following error message on localhost:3000 when trying to load

> undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13

```
@cabins =Cabin.group(:ship_id).count
@cabins.each do |group|
  @cabins_available <<group[1]
  @cabins_available <<group[1]
end
puts @cabins_available
```

here is the code

```
class TravelagentController < ApplicationController
def index
  @cruises = Cruise.all
  @cruise_names = []
  @cruises.each do |cruise|
    @cruise_names <<cruise.name
  end
  @cabins =Cabin.group(:ship_id).count
  @cabins.each do |group|
    @cabins_available <<group[1]
    @cabins_available <<group[1]
  end
  puts @cabins_available
  puts @cruise_names
 end
end
```

Comment: `@cabins_available` is a nil object instead of an array/AR object.

Comment: Show the code from `TravelAgentController#index`

Comment: Please copy and paste code and error messages into your question and do not link images. There are a couple of drawbacks with images: You cannot search the code, you cannot copy code into the answer and it makes your question not searchable later on for other people having similar questions.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and struggling to understand the rules of the group

Comment: Thank you for closing this question so it can't be answered. All I was asking for was a bit of help from this community and I get shot down... Ive changed the op now so if anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Please try to get the hang of basics from someone so that you are not "bullied" (as you might be thinking) here as your question is quite basic which I understand everyone started at some point but should be a part of self-thinking instead of posting here.

**How you should diagnose the issue:**

`nil` is "nothing" and in ruby it is put in `NilClass` and `NilClass` does not have most methods of `String` or `Integer` or `Array` classes. So, if the error message says `<<` is not a method for `nil` then it means you used this operator on something that you were assuming to be an array but it is `nil`.

Now, if you see that line 10: `@@cabins_available <<group[1]` has this error and the operator is being used on `@cabins_available` which should be an array but since it is `nil` and it is `nil` because you did not declare it before, you should declare it.

Please try not to **just** copy code of others or you will be clueless on every new step. Try researching on things, you see implemented, at least enough to understand them.

**Solution:**

```
class TravelagentController < ApplicationController
def index
  @cruises = Cruise.all
  @cruise_names = []
  @cabins_available = []
  @cruises.each do |cruise|
    @cruise_names <<cruise.name
  end
  @cabins =Cabin.group(:ship_id).count
  @cabins.each do |group|
    @cabins_available <<group[1]
    @cabins_available <<group[1]
  end
  puts @cabins_available
  puts @cruise_names
 end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I am new to developing, studying my masters degree actually, and am finding my feet. I wrote quite a vague question because I still have quite a basic understanding of the whole ruby universe!

I will try and implement this solution and hopefully this resolves the issue.

Comment: @BlairForbes It will. Then don't forget to accept it as an answer and upvoting after acceptance. Happy Coding :) I had upvoted your question to cancel one downvote considering you are new and at some point everybody is.